# Navigating pages with mutiple queries in tableau dashboard

Tags: javascript, jsp, tableau-api

I am trying to move my jsp graphs into tableau,

**What i currently have in my application:** 
 a JSP Page has Zoomable Circle Packing and on click of each label in the circle, it popup's a new jsp page(This jsp page has multiple graphs and tables just like a dashboard, this popup jsp page is dynamic)

**What i am trying to achieve:**   I am planning to build a zoomable circle packing graph in tableau and on click of each label, it should open a popup that has a dashboard

**Problem i am facing:** i imported oracle database into tableau, build a custom query and able to get a circle graph in one worksheet. now i am trying to click on each circle to navigate to dashboard (I am sure i will achieve), but i want to use a different sql query for dashboard. How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think what you're trying to do might be possible with dashboard Actions. You can have multiple data connections. An action can drive a different query as long as there is a similar dimension. If you can provide sample data, that would help diagnose if this is possible.

Comment: I want to pass the parameter from the tableau to a jsp page. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Showing a different dashboard with data based off the selection on the previous dashboard can be achieved with a dashboard action filter.

If you want the data you present in dashboard 2 to be from a different data source you'll need to ensure the data sources are linked by a common key (this is show by a red paperclip next to the dimension name).

Here's a link to a Tableau blog post on action filters, a good introduction:
https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/blog/2015/06/rough-guide-dashboard-actions